# How to control a user not to close all python messagebox error generated when appearing on taskbar?

Tags: python, python-2.7, messagebox

Hi i have a simple code that generate a message box.
My aim is to control the user by disabling close all functionality when i generate a multiple messagebox.

My Question is how to disable the close all capability of multiple messagebox generated? because for now it's closeable when i right-click on task bar.

```
def msgbox(self,hwnd,msg,thid,pid):
        MB_OK = 0x0
        MB_OKCXL = 0x01
        MB_YESNOCXL = 0x03
        MB_YESNO = 0x04
        MB_HELP = 0x4000
        ICON_EXLAIM=0x30
        ICON_INFO = 0x40
        ICON_STOP = 0x10
        MB_TOPMOST=0x40000
        MB_SYSTEMMODAL=0x1000
        """
                HEX VALUE LINK
        https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MsgBox.htm
        """
        writeLogs = WriteLogs(
                    pathLog = app_config['path_logs'] +"\\"+strftime("%Y_%m_%d")+".log",
                    timedate = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                    )
        writeLogs.appendLogA(msg)
        ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(hwnd, msg+str(operatorMessage), "[Error]", MB_OK | ICON_STOP | MB_SYSTEMMODAL)
```

Comment: That's nice. What's your question?

Comment: This is incomplete question, can you give more details?